# binary matrices with directional non-zero elements

Tags: image-processing, matlab

This question is in the context of image processing.

Assume I have a matrix of size 64 by 64. Assume even rows are all zero and odd rows are all one. I want to rotate the matrix `d` degrees. For example if I rotate it 90 degrees, then I will have a matrix with even columns equal to zero and odd columns equal to one. 
Is there an algorithm to do that easily? Given the matrix and `d` I want to rotate the elements. Matlab's `imrotate` won't work since after rotation I get some zeros at the corners. I know one way is to use `repmat`, rotate it and then crop it in the center. But that does not seem straightforward. Any smart ideas? For example, is it possible to define a formula to give the values of each element given d (and the fact that the matrix was originally `1 0 1 0...`?

Comment: Rotation for a discretized image are simple only in a few cases: typically multiples of $45°$. Also, what is your center of rotation? Depending on the precisions given, options could be proposed

Comment: center is at (0,0). I need one degree precision. So it should round the indices to the closest index to avoid a fractional index.

Comment: Is $(0,0)$ the top-left? Rounding is likely to produce "weird slanted lines". Off the top of my head, a $1°$ precision sounds illusory for a $64\times 64$. If you tell us the kind of processing you are looking at, this could help us further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that your image origins from sampling a continuous-spatial-domain 2-dimensional function, you can perform the sampling of this function with the rotated coordinates. HAve a look at this example:

```
N = 32  # 32 for simplicity
N2 = N/2
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))

# exemplary rotation around 5 degrees
angle = 5*np.pi/180
# perform rotation around the image center
nx = np.cos(angle)*(x-N2) - np.sin(angle)*(y-N2) + N2
ny = np.sin(angle)*(x-N2) + np.cos(angle)*(y-N2) + N2

# three functions that fulfill your constraint of even-odd 1-0
I_func1 = lambda x, y: 0.5*(1-np.cos(np.pi*y))
I_func2 = lambda x, y: (abs((y%2)-1)<=0.5).astype(float)
I_func3 = lambda x, y: (1-abs((y%2)-1)).astype(float)

# the original image
I = I_func1(x, y)

plt.figure()
t = np.linspace(0, N-1, 16*N)
t2 = np.arange(N)
plt.plot(t, I_func1(0, t))
plt.plot(t, I_func2(0, t))
plt.plot(t, I_func3(0,t))
plt.stem(t2, I_func(0, t2))
plt.xlim((0, 5))
plt.title('underlying continuous function')

plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(I, interpolation='none', cmap='gray')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(I_func1(nx, ny), interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
plt.title("Cos")

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(I_func2(nx, ny), interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
plt.title("rect")

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(I_func3(nx, ny), interpolation='none', cmap='gray')
plt.title("triang")
```

Output:
[image]

[image]

As you see, different functions yield different rotation results. Maybe this can help you to find an explicity formula?